# Not getting char array as output?

Tags: c++, string, input, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char addi[5];
string name;

string a="ADD:";

     fgets(addi,5, stdin);
     cin>>name;
     addi[5]='\0';

 cout<<"addi"<<addi<<endl;
```

i have a addi char array in which i wanna store "ADD:"  and name string in which i wanna store the string to be added .the input will be in format **ADD:wolf**  .why does addi not take the "ADD:" string?? OR alternatively how would i do it since i need to compare the ADD:  with some string in further steps.

Comment: `addi[5]='\0';` is illegal, it's past the end of that array.

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. What is your input? What is the actual output? And what output do you expected?

Comment: ADD:marsz
ADD:marsz
DEL:Dabrowski
DEL:z   ................ input is like this and i need to seperate the first 4 characters to decide wheather to **add** or  **delete** the string that follows . so i made a char array of size 5 and worked to input "ADD:" in that and the other string in name .

Comment: You do know that you are asking for input *twice*? If you only give one line of input, only the `fgets` call will be satisfied, and the input with `std::cin` will wait for input that you don't give.

Comment: And why are you using C arrays and mixing input methods? Use `std::string` and `std::cin` for both inputs.

Comment: so how should i do it ??

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you expect the `fgets` call to get the first four characters, and then use `std::cin` to get the remaining line. However it does not work like that. The `fgets` call gets the *complete line*, even it it only writes four characters to your buffer. Then the input with `std::cin` will wait for input that never comes.

Instead I suggest you read the complete line with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and then split the string at the colon to get the "key" and the "value".

---

Actually, since `std::getline` supports simple tokenization, you can use two calls to read the input:

```
std::string op;
std::string data;

std::getline(std::cin, op, ':');
std::getline(std::cin, data);
```

Now the string `op` will contain e.g. `ADD` (the string before the colon), and `data` will contain the string after the colon.

Comment: now when i compare **addi** with **a** string it gives me wrong ans.... . i have modified **a** string to **ADD**                                                                             getline(std::cin,addi,':');
         getline(std::cin,name);

cout<<"adi"<<addi<<"a"<<a<<endl;
         if(addi==a))
         {
             cout<<"in add";
            m[Hash(name)]=name;..........

Comment: @Hari The `addi` string you get with `getline` is *without* the semicolon, while `a` (in your example from the question) is *with* the colon. Is there anything else that differs? What ***is*** the output?

Comment: yeah i modified the **a**.not getting output  when i did **addi.compare(a)** it works well.

Comment: @Hari Have you tried stepping though your code, line by line, in a debugger? To see what really happens?